# famo.us : What is the difference between a View and a ContainerSurface?

Tags: famo.us, famous-angular

What is the difference between a [View](https://famo.us/docs/api/latest/core/View) and a [Container Surface](https://famo.us/docs/api/latest/surfaces/ContainerSurface)?

Both serve to encapsulate other nodes.

What is the difference between them ? In which case should I use one or the other ?